# testing for tags with no content with beautifulsoup python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I m working with BeautifulSoup in Python for scraping a webpage. The html under issue looks like below:

```
<td><a href="blah.html>blahblah</a></td>
<td>line2</td>
<td></td>
```

i wish to take the contents of the td tag. So for the first td, i need the "blahblah" text and for the next td, i want to write "line2" and for the last td, "blank" because there is no content.

my code snippet looks like this -

```
row = [] 
for each_td in td:                        
    link = each_td.find_all('a')                                                
    if link:
        row.append(link[0].contents[0])
        row.append(link[0]['href'])
    elif each_td.contents[0] is None:
        row.append('blank')                
    else:
        row.append(each_td.contents[0])
print row
```

However on running, i get the error -

```
elif each_td.contents[0] is None:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Note- i am working with beautifulsoup.

How do I test for the "no-content-td" and weite appropriately? Why is the "... is None" not working?

Answer (score 11):

Who said that 'contents' has always at least one element? Obviously you encounter the situation that 'contents' has no elements and therefore you will this error.

A more appropriate check would be:

```
if each_td.contents:
```

or

```
if len(each_td.contents) > 0:
```

But your preassumption is just wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `.text` to get the text.

```
row = [] 
for each_td in td:
    row.append(each_td.text)
print row
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the exception . Below is the code

```
try:
  row.append(each_td.contents[0])
except IndexError:
  //do what is required if it is empty ...
```