# Cannot count empty tags with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I've had a [look](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbeautifulsoup%5D%20cannot%20select%20class) for other questions convering this, but I couldn't find anything.

My HTML looks like

```
<div class="rating-input">
     <i data-value="1" class="rating-active-star"></i>
     <i data-value="2" class="rating-active-star"></i>
     <i data-value="3" class="rating-active-star"></i>
     <i data-value="4" class="rating-active-star"></i>
     <i data-value="5" class="rating-inactive-star"></i>
</div>
```

And my line that's failing is this:

```
details = [{"name": film.select('h2')[0].text.split('\n')[0],
            "rating":len(film.select('div i.rating-inactive-star'))} 
          for film in detail_row]
```

As it brings back this:

```
[{'name': 'The LEGO Batman Movie', 'rating': 0}, 
 {'name': 'Sing', 'rating': 0}, 
 {'name': 'John Wick: Chapter 2', 'rating': 0}, 
 {'name': 'Fifty Shades Darker', 'rating': 0}, 
 {'name': 'The Great Wall', 'rating': 0}, 
 {'name': 'Hidden Figures', 'rating': 0}, 
 {'name': 'La La Land', 'rating': 0}, 
 {'name': 'The Founder', 'rating': 0}, 
 {'name': 'Hacksaw Ridge', 'rating': 0}, 
 {'name': 'T2 Trainspotting', 'rating': 0}, 
 {'name': 'Split', 'rating': 0}, 
 {'name': 'Patriots Day', 'rating': 0}
]
```

Where all the ratings are zero. What I'm expecting are the number of `i` elements with the class `rating-active-star` (e.g. 4, for the above html).

Where as changing my rating selector from `'div i.rating-active-star'` to `'div i'` all the `'rating': 0` become `'rating': 5`

Here is my whole script (more or less an MVP):

```
import requests
import bs4
data = "si=1010841&sort=cin&max=0&bd=2017-02-23&css=cat-&mod=cinemapage_movie_list&attrs=2D%2C3D%2CIMAX%2CViP%2CVIP%2CDBOX%2C4DX%2CM4J%2CSS"
data_list = data.split('&')
info = {item[0]:item[1] for item in [elem.split('=') for elem in data_list]}
response = requests.post('https://www.cineworld.co.uk/pgm-list-byfeat',info)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
detail_row = soup.select('div[id^=film_] div.row div.col-sm-10')
details = [{"name": film.select('h2')[0].text.split('\n')[0],
            "rating":len(film.select('div i.rating-active-star'))}
          for film in detail_row]
```

Why does the length of a list of empty tags differ from the length of non-empty tags? And how do I work around this?

Comment: I'm confused. There's no values in the rating tags. So `len(film.select('div i.rating-active-star')))` is 0. And `len(film.select('div i')))` is 5. What were you expecting to see?

Comment: @Batman The number of tags with that class. I was assuming empty !=null. Is that wrong?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12336968/1075247 except I want to get a class not the text

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be elsewhere. This snippet seems to work as expected:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="rating-input">
 <i data-value="1" class="rating-active-star"></i>
 <i data-value="2" class="rating-active-star"></i>
 <i data-value="3" class="rating-active-star"></i>
 <i data-value="4" class="rating-active-star"></i>
 <i data-value="5" class="rating-inactive-star"></i>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print (len(soup.select('div i.rating-inactive-star')),
        len(soup.select('div i.rating-active-star')))
```